# Angular.js : Conditional binding for nested object

Tags: angularjs

I have my angular controller as below :

```
var isAuth = true;
    $scope.Dashboard = function (isAuth) {
        $scope.DashboardActions = [{
            AreaName: 'Create Request',
            Functions: [{
                FunctionName: 'Request Grid',
                Actions: {
                    View: isAuth,
                    Sort: isAuth,
                    Filter: isAuth,
                    EditLink: isAuth
                }
            }, {
                FunctionName: 'Create Dummy Request',
                Actions: {
                    Enable: (isAuth) ? 'inline-block' : 'None'
                }
            }]
        }];
    };
```

and HTML as :

```
<span style="display:{{Enable | Function {'FunctionName', 'Create Dummy Request'} | DashboardActions }}" class="Action">Actions                            
                            <a href="#/REQUEST/0" class="btn btn-primary">Create Dummy Request Test</a>
```

I want to enable disable the `span` with class `Action` with respect to `Enable` property. How can I do it? Sorry, just learning Angular these days...

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p048v4xL/)

Comment: I'd suggest you move most of your logic into `controller`, than just use `ng-if` in a view

Answer (score 0):

You use `ng-class` to conditionally apply classes to DOM objects. See the [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ng/directive/ngClass) for more information.

Furthermore, you need to call `Dashboard()` on init since it builds the object you want to use. For that, you can use `ng-init`.

See the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p048v4xL/1/).

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the indexes `DashboardActions[0].Functions[1].Actions.Enable`

Comment: you can use `angular.forEach()` to loop through your arrays then.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-style` or `ng-class` to apply conditional styling with $scope variable. Also you need to initialize `$scope.Dashboard()` function. Remember, if it's needed to check a lot of conditions to determine which class gets active, use a function to check the conditions. Remove conditions checking in HTML as the HTML page gets heavy. [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p048v4xL/2/) is one of the many possible solutions of your question.

Comment: What if I dont want to hadcode the indexes `DashboardActions[0].Functions[1].Actions.Enable`

Comment: It depends how you want to check the condition. Do you want to iterate `DashboardActions` in HTML?